# Blog Link in magento

Tags: magento, url, blogs, backend

I'm working in magento blog
i have 2 store views each one for different country

the problem is when we add the blog link in the social media page .. we must to write only one store view in the URL

How can i add a blog URL that match with customer store view

ex: if customer from store view 1 open the link .. the URL will be (example.com/storeview1/blog)
and if customer from store view 2 open the link .. the URL will be (example.com/storeview2/blog)

I tried to make the URL be (example.com/blog) 
but it refers to 404 page

Comment: Are u using any extenison for wordpress/magento integration?

Comment: No .. it installed from back-end>blog

Comment: Sorry . yes it's installed extension

Comment: Tell me the name of extension.

Comment: AHEADWORKS EXTENSIONS

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Open Admin panel
2. Goto System->Configuration
3. Change **Current Configuration Scope** to storeview1 or storeview2 from top of leftbar.
4. search for keyword blog under "aheadWorks Extensions" at leftbar
5. Try to change  **Route to Blog** from settings.

Hope this will help some how.

Comment: in step 5 .. change Route to Blog to what?

Comment: I cant tell the exact solution. but you can try **storeview1/blog** over there.